# Google services location API Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app that if a user is in a certain location they can find all the closest mechanic in their area without having to type in "mechanic" into a search bar. Is there an API available where I can do this in Android Studio or is their any tutorials or examples, Thanks [image]"

Comment: This question is rather broad for SO. Please be more precise if you need more information about querying Google for mechanics, about creating the user interface or generally about accessing Google services from Android.

Comment: Don't post such general requirement here. First google it how to achieve the same. Whether you should implement your server with logic based on google api's or is it possible with google places api....

Comment: Do you want to get customized mechanics or filtered search google maps mechanics?

Comment: @MaheshGiri I don't want the user to have to search for a mechanic in their area via a search bar, instead I want just to retrieve a list of mechanics automatically in their area e.g. 50 mile radious

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have records about mechanics and location details also. If you have enough information than you can get your location by [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) and then calculate location distance with you current location and mechanics location information. On the basis of the that you can display mechanics details near by location.

Answer (score 0):

yes you may do this like this

1. Create one service which is used for  getting location updates.
2. Search for those locations mechanic on server after getting getting list show that list in markers.

Comment: Thanks, Would you happen to have any examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

You may Use [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). You need to pass current latitude and longitude of current location(you may use LocationService for getting latitude and longitude),radius,Location type and api key. It's very simple

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=YOUR_LATITUDE,YOUR_LONGITUDE&radius=50000&types=bus_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY